# Transfer BTC from paper wallet without 3rd party (like blockchain.com etc)

Tags: paper-wallet

I have btc on my paper wallet and I want to transfer to some other address. How can I do this without sharing my private key to some other site like blockchain.com or electrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrum does not share your private key with its server. I would use Electrum as it's very convenient, well-maintained and it does not have large storage requirements.

- Create new wallet
- File > Sweep private key

Some other options are:

- Bitcoin Core, which expects you to download the whole blockchain. Use the `importprivkey` command.
- BRD wallet, which is my favorite mobile wallet that can [sweep from QR](https://brd.com/support/articles/234979507).
- CoPay mobile wallet also has [the same feature](https://support.bitpay.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004344486-How-do-I-sweep-a-paper-wallet-into-BitPay-Copay-).

Electrum and Bitcoin Core are the two most popular desktop wallets. (Core was actually designed as a full node, therefore it's not very user-friendly and not the best wallet). I'm not aware of a third desktop wallet.

Comment: how can I trust Electrum? is it open source?

Comment: Yes, it's here: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum @kilonet